# I want to know how to generate first autonumber in c#.net

Tags: c#

I type this code to get an autonumber in C#.net :

```
public void AutoNumber()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Ganesh;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Max(Eid) as Tot FROM Employee_Payment", con);

    SqlDataReader dr;

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Tot"]);
        if (i > 0)
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            txtid.Text = Convert.ToString(j);

        }
        else
        {
            txtid.Text = "101";
        }

    }

    con.Close();
}
```

But when database not contain any records it shows Error `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.`

Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: Where exactly is it failing?  Why not just check for DBNullbeofre performing whatever action is failing?  Anyhow, this is off-topic for SU. I'd vote to migrate to StackOverflow, but this isn't quality enough (you haven't included any research).

Comment: I would look to have the database provide the identity field rather  than your own .net code. Research Identity and AutoNumber.

Comment: This is conceptually wrong and implemented wrong. Use autonumbering if you ever want more than one user to use this code.

Answer (score 1):

The method you have chose is unreliable for a couple of reasons.  First off, as you've found, if the table has no rows, it's impossible to determine the current Identity value for the column.  Additionally, if you were to delete the row with the highest `Eid` you would get incorrect results.  You can get the current value of the Identity column using the following query:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Employee_Payment') AS Current_Identity
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply create an identity column in your DB and set it to autonumber for you?

If you have to do it this way,then if your table contains no rows, create one and assign Eid to 1, then insert